# Is urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:emailAddress a valid NameID format?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

In the OASIS specs I can read the following valid nameid-formats:

- urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
- urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
- urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
- urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
- urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName
- urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:WindowsDomainQualifiedName
- urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:kerberos
- urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity

but can't find urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:emailAddress.

If I do a fast google search, this format appears several times, including a documentation of [Cisco Spark](https://support.ciscospark.com/customer/portal/articles/1909112-sso-setup).

Can someone clarify to me this issue? It seems that someone invented this nameid-format and now some IdP/SP using it.

Answer (score 12):

@smartin -- You appear to work at OneLogin and I recently submitted a ticket about this :-). I think your hunch is right; someone saw that there is a SAML 1.1 and a SAML 2.0 and assumed that the 1.1 in `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress` was a mistake.

Section 8 of the specification document mentions this at the beginning:

> The following sections define URI-based identifiers for common resource access actions, subject name identifier formats, and attribute name formats. Where possible an existing URN is used to specify a protocol. In the case of IETF protocols, the URN of the most current RFC that specifies the protocol is used. URI references created specifically for SAML have one of the following stems, according to the specification set version in which they were first introduced:
>
> ```
> urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:
> urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:
> urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:
> ```

http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf

As the e-mail address identifier was introduced back in SAML v1.1, that would make sense. Check out section 7 intro and 7.3.2 here (https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/3406/oasis-sstc-saml-core-1.1.pdf).

So, tl;dr: `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:emailAddress` is in conflict with the SAML 1.1 and SAML 2.0 specs.

Comment: Yes, I work at OneLogin and I collaborated in your ticket.
I wanted to see if someone at OASIS can provide some more info and confirm what we discovered, so we can ask the IdP/SP to follow the standard ;)